# Busy indicator in pseudo after element next to/outside button

Tags: html, css

I want to display a css based busy indicator next to a submit button. I use the after pseudo element for this, but I fail to place the indicator icon next to/ outside the button.

Obviously I can add a rule like `left: 100px` to push it right and outside the button, but that is not what I am looking for: still the space is reserved inside the button. I cannot use absolute positioning, since the button text is flexible (translations).

So I guess my question is something like "how to I take the after pseudo element out of the flow" or similar.

Note that I do *not* want to embed the button inside an additional container to place the busy indicator inside the DOM.

Here is a small example to illustrate what I mean: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5avjzq3/)

The HTML markup:

```
<button>text on button</button>
```

The CSS rules:

```
button{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 60px;
}
button:after{
    content: url("https://skitch-img.s3.amazonaws.com/20120509-qf93juewhfhk69k9i42kfxbi3r.png");
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't understand this:

> I can add a rule like left: 100px to push it right and outside the button, but that is not what I am looking for: still the space is reserved inside the button. I cannot use absolute positioning, since the button text is flexible (translations)

What do you mean?

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zephod/641Lsy89/) which appears to solve your problem. Give the element `absolute` positioning, and give it a negative `right` value to push it beyond the right-hand-edge of the parent.

If this answer is not correct can you produce a Fiddle illustrating the problem?

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. I completely failed to think about a negative positioning. Thanks!

Comment: :-) As it is correct, can you give it the Approved Answer tick?

Comment: As soon as I waited long enough to value other answers :-)

Comment: Sorry, but this actually does _not_ solve the problem, if I am not totally mistaken: although I did not state that in an explicit manner it appears obvious to me that such a button is not the only element on a page. So it is embedded inside some container with a bigger width than the button itself. using an absolute placement and a negative right positioning results in a placement relative to the containers right border, doesn't it? Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/641Lsy89/1/

Comment: This line: `div : 100%;` produces very non-standard behaviour and is breaking things. Where did this come from?

Comment: My problems with the positioning in the original project were cause by additional hidden elements. I didn't realize that myself, this is why all obvious things somehow didn't work. Thanks for putting my back to the straight line!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that's what you mean but try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/h5avjzq3/2/

Basically, since the button is dynamic in width, I use

```
margin-left: calc(100% + 10px);
position: absolute;
left: 0;
```

that will make sure the button is always right to the button, but you have to actually reserve the space now. (you said it's already done)

Comment: I guess the only thing better about this answer than the previous is you don't have to take into account the size of the loading icon when defining margins.

Comment: This is an interesting approach and it works around some other influences. But I fail to get this placement really independent of the text length.

Comment: Also it suffers from the same issue as I mentioned in Toms answer.

Comment: If the button is too large, you can't expect it to shrink to fit you row, however, you can add margin-right: ~80px to your button and that will make sure it will always have place for your loading spinner.

Comment: I do not have a problem with enough room for the spinner. I am talking about its placement.